# Push the value returned from a promise into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have this basic google map api in react which just puts some markers on the map in componentDidMount.
To do that I need to use Geocode in order to convert a location (Green Street, nr.11, New York) to a latitude, longitude pair. This part works fine and the code is bellow:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let usersLocations = [];
    this.props.users.map(user => {
      const userAddress =
        "Street " + user.street + " " + user.nr + ", " + user.city;
      Geocode.fromAddress(userAddress).then(
        response => {
          const result = { user: user, coord: response.results[0] };
          userLocations.push(result);
        },
        error => {}
      );
    });
    console.log(usersLocations) //outputs []
  }
```

The thing is, if I setState directly into the callback from Geocode, I'm doing this multiple times since I'm iterating over the users from the props.
What I thought was to push each location into an array and then setState once for the entire array.
The problem is, I can't push the result into the array since I'm in the callback and by the time I get the response from geocode the usersLocations array has been logged to the console already.
How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to collect all the data before setting the state

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all(this.props.users.map(user => {
      const userAddress =
        "Street " + user.street + " " + user.nr + ", " + user.city;
      return Geocode.fromAddress(userAddress).then(
        response => ({ user: user, coord: response.results[0]}),
        error => {}
      );
    })).then(usersLocations => this.setState({ usersLocations }));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense what you're saying. But, I just tried this and returns an array of undefined values. (3 in this case because I have 3 users) What can be the cause of this? EDIT: Never mind, I just had a typo. Thanks!